# What are the memory implications of calling trackAllColumnsForAutoSIzing in Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using Apache Poi I have converted my code for writing data to an Excel spreadsheet from HSSF to SXSSF to allow a smaller memory footprint when writing large files. The one issue I had was trying to resize the columns according to the data with

```
for (int 0 = 1; i < next.getMapping().size(); i++)
{
     next.getSheet().autoSizeColumn(i);
}
```

was now failing complaining my columns were not tracked

I fixed the issue by adding first

```
((SXSSFSheet)next.getSheet()).trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
```

This line and the resizing code I call just before the final save

```
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
workbook.dispose();
```

What I am not clear about is

1. The memory implications of this, does it suddenly have to read in all the data into memory or does it just iterate round finding the longest value
2. I only do this at the end so does it actually consider all data or just the final **n** rows, where **n** was the value used when originally constructed SXSSFWorkbook

**Update**
So I have looked at the javadoc for SXSSFSheet at [https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing()]
and it says

> Adjusts the column width to fit the contents.
>
> This process can be relatively slow on large sheets, so this should
>   normally only be called once per column, at the end of your
>   processing. You can specify whether the content of merged cells should
>   be considered or ignored. Default is to ignore merged cells.
>
> Special note about SXSSF implementation: You must register the columns
>   you wish to track with the SXSSFSheet using
>   trackColumnForAutoSizing(int) or trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing(). This
>   is needed because the rows needed to compute the column width may have
>   fallen outside the random access window and been flushed to disk.
>   Tracking columns is required even if all rows are in the random access
>   window.
>
> New in POI 3.14 beta 1: auto-sizes columns using cells from current
>   and flushed rows.

It doesn't give any warnings about memory just slowness, and it also says it considers all rows but I am on 3.15 and I don't think it is considering all rows. I have some columns where the data takes less space the column header in row zero yet the spreadsheet created has the columns widths of columns smaller than the the width of the header in the first row.

I could quite easily store the width of the data as I process each row and store the widest data. However although I can use setColumnWidth() how do I account for different fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Apache POI is open source, you can [read the implementation code and see how it works!](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/AutoSizeColumnTracker.java)

Tracking a column doesn't have much of a memory footprint impact, because the main storage is only one object per column:

```
Map<Integer, ColumnWidthPair> maxColumnWidths = 
                              new HashMap<Integer, ColumnWidthPair>();
```

What tracking will do is slow down adding of rows, because for each cell in a tracked column, POI will have to work out how wide the cell is before flushing it to disk.

If your file is predictable, it's often best to turn on tracking of all columns, write out the first few 10s of lines, then turn off tracking to the end of the file. That'll get you a good guess of the widths, without having to calculate for every cell.

However, if you have no idea of what row will contain the longest values for each cell, you'll need to take the slight performance hit and track all columns and all rows throughout the file. It's not *too* much more work than not doing it though

Comment: Thanks what you say make sense, but for any row many of the coliumns will be blank so I cant accurately get width by checking just the first 100 rows or so. And I find with a 20,000 row spreadsheet the performance hit of enabling autoResize() is significant adding a minute onto processing time. So I am now manually recording the largest width for each column as I add the rows, then passing this value * 256 to set setColumnWidth() just before final write and this is not hitting performance.